# Accessing properties of subclasses and superclasses in java with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have a number of classes that derive from the same base type. The base type contains all the members common to the subclasses. When subclass is instantiated, I need to access its members through reflection. I need to access all the members of each subclass, but I need to isolate those members that exist in the base class from those that exists in subclasses. For instance:

```
public abstract class mainBaseClass{
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
}
public class subClass extends mainBaseClass{
    public String property1;
    public String property2;
}
```

I am accessing members as follows:

```
Field[] fields = objectName.getClass().getFields();
for(Field f : fields){
    Log.d("FIELD NAME", f.getName());
}
```

When I use reflection to expose the properties contained in an instance of "subClass" how would I differentiate 'firstname' and 'lastname' from 'property1' and 'property2'?

I'm not sure how to implement this. Can somebody offer a solution or maybe a place to look? Thank you! Vivian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Class#getDeclaredFields()` instead. [Java-Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29):

Returns an array of `Field` objects reflecting all the fields
declared by the class or interface represented by this
`Class` object. This includes public, protected, default
(package) access, and private fields, **but excludes inherited fields.**

Comment: Is there a method that returns only the members of the base class?

Comment: `class.getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields()`, don't forget to check that superClass is not null